# Firebase functions config randomly disappears

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an environment variable set in Firebase Functions using the below command:

```
firebase functions:config:set email.address="mail@example.com"
```

I access it in my function via the following:

```
functions.config().email.address;
```

It *seems* like every 30 days I have to manually set the config again because the functions that use the config throw this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

And then it runs fine after I set the config and redeploy my functions again. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I just ran the CLI command to get my Functions config (I set them a few months ago) and it still exists. Could you double check if someone is unsetting the variables and redeploys your function? https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-management

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo I'm the only one that's one this project atm but I'll still follow your lead

Comment: Feel free to contact support if you're not seeing actionable information on your end. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact